# $(\cos x)^{\sin x}$ derivative if $\cos x$ is negative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

I am trying to find the derivative of $(\cos x)^{\sin x}$. I used the transformation to $e^{\sin x \ln (\cos x)}$, but what if $\cos x$ is negative....? What to do? The $\ln$ won't be appropriate

Comment: The function is periodic, so you only need to know the derivative for a period. Also please add more [detail](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: If $\cos(x)$ is negative, $(\cos(x))^{\sin(x)}$ probably won't be real

Comment: It's well defined on $(\pi/2,\pi/2)$ so calculate the derivative on that interval, and then add a little note about $\cos x <0.$

Comment: The common rule is that negative numbers cannot be exponentiated to non-integer power. So if we deal with function of real (not complex) variable, case $\cos x<0$ lies outside of function domain.

Comment: Before discussing how to find the derivative of $(\cos x)^{\sin x}$ when $\cos x$ is negative, you need to decide what it means to take a non-integer power ( which the $\sin x$ will typically be) of a negative number.

Comment: It is always better to remember as a rule of thumb: $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is defined only when $f(x)>0$ (and of course the domains of $f$ and $g$).

Answer (score 2):

You can't take the derivative of $(\cos x)^{\sin x}$ if $\cos x$ is negative. The function is not even well defined for values of $x$ where $\cos x$ is negative. In these zones, the function starts behaving like $f(x)=x^x$ (look the behaviour of this function up). Also, look up the graoh of $(\cos x)^{\sin x}$ on Desmos- it may really help.

Comment: Begin your answer with the explanation that you deal only with the case of real values.

Answer (score 1):

What if we allow complex values?
Of course $f(x) = (\cos x)^{\sin x}$ has derivative $$f'(x) = (\cos x)^{(\sin x)+1}\log(\cos x) - (\cos x)^{(\sin x) - 1}\sin^2 x.$$  As we often see with exponents in complex numbers, this is a "multivalued function".  Maple graphs this using "principal value" for these multivalued functions:

Graph of the real part
[image: real]
has a vertical asymptote at $x=3\pi/2$.

Graph of the imaginary part.
[image: imag]
has a jump at $x=3\pi/2$ where it changes from one branch to another.

Answer (score 0):

$$y=(\cos x)^{\sin x} \tag 1 $$

Due to negative base, logarithm  would be complex. For $(a,b) $ positive in general

$$ \log_{( -b\;)}a= \frac{\log a }{\log b + (2k-1) \pi};\tag 2 $$

Next take log for (1) and differentiate w.r.t $x$

$$\frac{y'}{y}= \cos x \cdot \log (\cos x) -\frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos x}$$

$$y'= \log (\cos x) \cdot\cos x ^{ (\sin x +1)} -{\sin^2 x}\cdot {\cos x }^{ (\sin x -1)} \tag 3 $$
would be also complex, can be evaluated by applying (2).